# PHP - reduce multiple slashes to single slash

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a regular expression that I use to reduce multiple slashes to single slashes. The purpose is to read a url that is previously converted to a human readable link using mod_rewrite in apache, like this :

```
http://www.website.com/about/me
```

This works :

```
$uri = 'about//me';
$uri = preg_replace('#//+#', '/', $uri);
echo $uri; // echoes 'about/me'
```

This doesn't work :

```
$uri = '/about//me';
$uri = preg_replace('#//+#', '/', $uri);
echo $uri; // echoes '/about/me'
```

I need to be able to work with each url parameter alone, but in the second example, if I explode the trailling slash, it would return me 3 segments instead of 2 segments. I can verify in PHP if any if the parameters is empty, but as I'm using that regular expression, it would be nice if the regular expression already take care of that for me, so that I don't need to worry about segment validation.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

str_replace may be faster in this case

```
$uri = str_replace("//","/",$uri)
```

Secondly: use trim: http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

```
$uri = trim($uri,"/");
```

Comment: Or specially ltrim() or rtrim().

Comment: no, but my script combined with trim, handled all the slashes my fingers could type untill I got tired, so .. :)

Answer (score 6):

This converts double slashes in a string to a single slash, but the advantage of this code is that the slashes in the protocol portion of the string (`http://`) are kept.

```
preg_replace("#(^|[^:])//+#", "\\1/", $str);
```

Comment: Excuse me for description lack.Actually I use this code for converting double slashes in a string to a single slash,but the advantage of this code is:Except those found in http://

Comment: Best answer here :)

Answer (score 2):

How about running a second replace on $uri?

```
$uri = preg_replace('#^/#', '', $uri);
```

That way a trailing slash is removed. Doing it all in one preg_replace beats me :)
Using ltrim could also be a way to go (probably even faster).

Answer (score 2):

> I need to be able to work with each
>   url parameter alone, but in the second
>   example, if I explode the trailling
>   slash, it would return me 3 segments
>   instead of 2 segments.

One fix for this is to use preg_split with the third argument set to `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`:

```
$uri = '/about//me';
$uri_segments = preg_split('#/#', $uri, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
// $uri_segments[0] == 'about';
// $uri_segments[1] == 'me';
```

Answer (score 1):

You may split the string via `preg_split` instead, skipping the sanitizing altogether. You still have to deal with the empty chunks, though.

Answer (score 1):

you can combine all three alternatives into one regexp

```
$urls = array(
   'about/me',
   '/about//me',
   '/about///me/',
   '////about///me//'
);

print_r(
     preg_replace('~^/+|/+$|/(?=/)~', '', $urls)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Late but all these methods will remove `http://` slashes too, but this.

```
function to_single_slashes($input) {
    return preg_replace('~(^|[^:])//+~', '\\1/', $input);
}

# out: http://localhost/lorem-ipsum/123/456/
print to_single_slashes('http:///////localhost////lorem-ipsum/123/////456/');
```